# CodeForces Little Pony and Lord Tirek verdict get different output from my PC

Tags: c++

I try to solve this problem.
Little Pony and Lord Tirek
http://codeforces.com/contest/453/problem/E

and here is my solution

```
/*
HahaTTpro
Little Pony and Lord Tirek
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/453/E

*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct  pony
{
    long startMana;
    long regenMana;
    long maxMana;
    long curMana;

};

class Problem
{
private:
    pony *Pony;
    long totalPonies;
    long time;
    long totalMana;

    void killPony();
    void regen(long newtime);
    long drain(long target);
public:
    ~Problem();
    void inputPony();
    int instruction(long t, long r, long l);
    int getTotalPony(){
        return totalPonies;
    };
};



void Problem::inputPony()
{
    cin >> totalPonies;
    Pony = new pony[totalPonies];
    for (long i = 0; i < totalPonies; i++)
    {
        cin >> Pony[i].startMana;
        cin >> Pony[i].maxMana;
        cin >> Pony[i].regenMana;
        Pony[i].curMana = Pony[i].startMana;
    }

}

void ::Problem::killPony()
{
    delete[]Pony;
}

Problem::~Problem()
{
    killPony();
}

void Problem::regen(long newtime)
{
    long dentatime = newtime - time;
    for (long i = 0; i < totalPonies; i++)
    {
        Pony[i].curMana = Pony[i].curMana + Pony[i].regenMana*dentatime;
        if (Pony[i].curMana > Pony[i].maxMana) Pony[i].curMana = Pony[i].maxMana;
    }
    time = newtime;
}

long Problem::drain(long target)
{
    long result = 0;
    result = Pony[target].curMana;
    Pony[target].curMana = 0;
    return result;
}

int Problem::instruction(long t, long l, long r)
{
    regen(t);
    l--;
    r--;
    int res=0;
    for (long i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
        res=res + drain(i);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    Problem LittlePoNy;
    LittlePoNy.inputPony();
    long m;
    int t, l, r;
    cin >> m;
    int *Result;
    Result = new int[m];
    for (long i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> t >> l >> r;
        Result[i] = LittlePoNy.instruction(t, l, r) ;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << Result[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

//wtf ?
```

and verdict : http://codeforces.com/contest/453/submission/7334245 
on my pc
Input

```
5
0 10 1
0 12 1
0 20 1
0 12 1
0 10 1
2
5 1 5
19 1 5
```

output

```
25 
58
```

but on verdict, it got

```
35
58
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Step 1: start a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the member variable "time" is not initialized before being used.

Comment: yeah. Thanks. I add time=0 and verdict run fine, give correct output ... until test 12 where time limit is exceed :D